# tmux set-titles stopped woorking for rxvt-unicode

Tags: tmux, rxvt

Suddenly my tmux stopped to change terminal window title for `rxvt-unicode`. The only major change I remember doing last week was updating `bash`.

It'still working with `xterm`, so it may be something strictly with `rxvt`.

Here are my current versions:

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name               Version        Architecture   Description
+++-==================-==============-==============-==========================================
ii  bash               4.3-7ubuntu1.1 amd64          GNU Bourne Again SHell
ii  rxvt-unicode       9.19-1         amd64          RXVT-like terminal emulator with Unicode s
ii  tmux               1.8-5          amd64          terminal multiplexer
```

And here, fragments of my conf files:

[.bashrc](https://github.com/paulodiovani/dot-files/blob/master/home/diovani/.bashrc)

```
# Start tmux at login
# If not running interactively, do not do anything
[[ $- != *i* ]] && return
[[ -z "$TMUX" ]] && exec tmux
```

[.Xdefaults](https://github.com/paulodiovani/dot-files/blob/master/home/diovani/.Xdefaults)

```
URxvt.background:       #1E2B20
URxvt.foreground:       wheat
URxvt.fading:           25
URxvt.scrollBar:        0
!URxvt.font:             -*-fixed-medium-r-semicondensed-*-13-*-*-*-*-*-*-*
!URxvt.font:             xft:Inconsolata:pixelsize=15
URxvt.font:             xft:Ubuntu Mono:pixelsize=15
URxvt.color10:          #66ff66
URxvt.color12:          #6666ff
URxvt.borderLess:       0
URxvt.termName:         rxvt
URxvt.urlLauncher:      google-chrome
URxvt.loginShell:       1

! Font resize extension
URxvt.perl-ext-common: ...,font-size
URxvt.keysym.C-S-Up:   perl:font-size:increase
URxvt.keysym.C-S-Down: perl:font-size:decrease
```

[.tmux.conf](https://github.com/paulodiovani/dot-files/blob/master/home/diovani/.tmux.conf)

```
# turn on window titles
set -g set-titles on

# set wm window title string
set -g set-titles-string '#W'

# automatically set window title
setw -g automatic-rename on
```

How can I make it work again? Am I forgetting something?

Answer (score 1):

The `$TERM` is set to `rxvt`, in `.Xdefaults`. Setting it to `rxvt-unicode` fiz the problem.

in `.Xdefaults`:

```
URxvt.termName:         rxvt-unicode
```